# Plot a histogram based on a value in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, histogram

I have a dataset looking like this:

```
Result    test_value  File_id
Ok         2231         3
Ok         3322         32
No         1000          1
ok         4300          45
No         3999          ...
```

This is a dataframe. I am trying to plot a histogram for this to see how many values are Ok and how many values are No.

I did:
`plot_test=data['value'].hist(by=data['Result'],sharex=True,bins=10)` And I get 2 plots ,

1 plot for No and 1 Plot for Ok.

[image]

I would like to see just 1 histogram, with Ok values and No values with 2 different colors.

Comment: can you use seaborn.?

Comment: yea.. but didnt get a solution using seaborn

Comment: Are you looking for something shown here : https://python-graph-gallery.com/25-histogram-with-several-variables-seaborn/

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to get histograms for yes and no in the same plot itself. Is that it.?

Comment: No..sepa length and sepa width are two columns and they are plotted on the same axis. I want to plot one column 'testvalues' based on 2 unique values in 'result' column.

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: check my answer. Is that what you are looking for.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting `'Result'` as your `hue`

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(x='test_value', hue='Result',data=data)
```

Comment: Thanks...It worked but I modified it slightly:`code` sns.catplot(x='result', y='test_value',data=data)...this solution worked perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can use seaborn for this task. You have to make calls for `distplot` with the needed rows only.

See the code below,

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot( df.loc[df['Result'] == 'Ok']['Value'] , color="skyblue", label="Ok")
sns.distplot( df.loc[df['Result'] == 'No']['Value'] , color="red", label="No");
```

Using the sample data you posted, running this code generates the plot like this,

```
sns.distplot(df.loc[df['Result'] == 'Ok']['test_value'])
sns.distplot(df.loc[df['Result'] == 'No']['test_value']);
```

[image]

`df.dtypes` for the sample is

```
Result        object
test_value     int64
File_id       object
dtype: object
```

Comment: It gives an error "'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"... I changed the OK and no to int values as '1' and '0' in the dataframe..it gives "invalid type comparison"

Comment: what is the output of `data.dtypes`

Comment: result is object and test_value is int64....if i change to 1 and 0 in the result the it is int64

Comment: There is no column named `test_value` in the dataframe you posted in the question, edit the question to show a sample of the dataframe